# How can i change in R the font family of a Title with officer?

Tags: r, xml, ggplot2, officer

How can I change the font family of a title in R with officer? I'm trying this with the function `fp_text(font.family = "Arial")`, but the problem is that the title which I define with `fp_text` does not end up in the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a pain, but the way I do it is:

1. Add an empty placeholder in the title slot with `ph_empty()`
2. Add formatted text with `ph_add_fpar()`, using `fpar()`, `ftext()`, and `fp_text()` to create the formatted text object.

Here is an example of how to change the title on a Title Slide and on a Title and Content slide, assuming the fonts you want to use are "Rage Italic" and "Goudy Stout":

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

# the formatting you want to use goes here -- check your fonts()
format_main_title <- fp_text(font.family='Rage Italic', font.size=72)
format_page_title <- fp_text(font.family='Goudy Stout', font.size=24)

read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = 'Title Slide', master='Office Theme') %>%
  ph_empty(type='ctrTitle') %>%
  ph_add_fpar(fpar(ftext('Fancy Main Title', prop=format_main_title)), 
                      type = 'ctrTitle') %>%
  add_slide(layout = 'Title and Content', master='Office Theme') %>%
  ph_empty(type='title') %>%
  ph_add_fpar(fpar(ftext('Fancy Page Title', prop=format_page_title)), 
                                     type = 'title')  %>%
  ph_with_text(type = 'body', str = 'Boring stuff goes here') %>%
  print('test.pptx')
```

produces:

[image]

You can see these titles in the table of contents:

[image]

Having said that -- If you find yourself consistently changing title fonts to the same new formatting you would probably be better off creating a template deck with your own Slide Master (versus the default "Office Theme") that uses your desired font and beginning your chain with that (i.e., `read_pptx('your_template.pptx') %>% etc.`)

Comment: This returns the error `Error: selection does not match any row in slide_summary. Use function slide_summary.` after the third line.